# MySQL keeps crashing: InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11

Tags: mysql, debian

I have a simple webserver (Debian 6.0 x86, DirectAdmin with 1 GB of memory and still 10 GB free space, mySQl version 5.5.9), however the mySQL server keeps crashing and I need to kill all mySQL processes to be able to restart it again.

`/var/log/mysql-error.log` output:

```
130210 21:04:26 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
130210 21:04:34 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130210 21:05:42 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130210 21:05:48 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130210 21:06:22 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130210 21:06:27 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/website.pid ended
130210 21:06:29 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/website.pid ended
130210 21:07:22 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130210 21:07:51 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/website.pid ended
130210 21:08:33 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
130210 21:12:03 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130210 21:12:47 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130210 21:12:47 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use InnoDB's own implementation
130210 21:12:47 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
130210 21:12:47 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
130210 21:13:11 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
130210 21:13:23 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
130210 21:14:05  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
130210 21:17:53  InnoDB: Unable to open the first data file
InnoDB: Error in opening ./ibdata1
130210 21:17:53  InnoDB: Operating system error number 11 in a file operation.
```

I have found a topic on the mySQL website [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,139843,139843#msg-139843) however there's no solution for it.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I don't understand - this part of log file tells about problem with MySQL start not about cause of error. The best thing is to remove source of the problem.

Comment: Did you check that there was no running mysqld before starting it? How?

Comment: In my case, it happened because both docker and kubernetes were trying to access the same MySQL data location.

Answer (score 47):

another approach from one comment in the same blog:

> this helped me:
>
> lsof -i:3306
>
> Then kill it (the process number)
>
> kill -9 PROCESS
>
> e.g. kill -9 13498
>
> Then try to restart MySQL again.

via http://www.webhostingtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-1070293.html

Comment: `service mysql restart` was showing no running process already, but `lsof` found it. Killed it, `service mysql start`, and now the flood of process failed emails can stop. Many thanks.

Comment: Do not `kill -9`. It is almost always a bad idea. Use regular `kill` (aka `kill -TERM`). If that fails, try `kill -QUIT`. Only if that fails too, use `kill -9`, and then carefully check for inconsistencies afterwards.

Answer (score 30):

**Solution**

make a copy of the original files (ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1...).

```
mv ibdata1 ibdata1.bak 
cp -a ibdata1.bak ibdata1
```

http://cglreport.zhenhua.info/2008/08/mysql-error-unable-to-lock-ibdata1.html

archived link: https://web.archive.org/web/20120718013320/http://cglreport.zhenhua.info/2008/08/mysql-error-unable-to-lock-ibdata1.html

Comment: magically helped me.

Comment: what is the point of cp -a ?, I've already read man page

Comment: Many thanks, it helped. But why?

Comment: I had this problem after a failed restart on a db running in a docker container.  I am making an educated guess as to why this works and it is that some meta data is stored in the file.  moving it and copying it to it's original location removes the metadata determining it is locked.  the -a operation maintains the file attributes, including SELinux related attributes, but not the metadata, during the copy.

Comment: I am using kubernetes, so restarting `mysql`, or performing `service restart` is not an option, as it destroys the pod. However, if these files are in a persistence volue (which was my case), this is the answer you are looking for! worked flawlessly for me.

Answer (score 30):

with ubuntu 14.04. I'm experiencing this problem when I try to restart via

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Instead try

```
service mysql restart
```

Comment: @too http://askubuntu.com/questions/2075/whats-the-difference-between-service-and-etc-init-d

Comment: @too, if you have both an old-style init.d script **and** an upstart config for a job, you have to use `service job start`, otherwise if you start it with the init.d script, Upstart will not know about it and it could attempt to boot another instance. (At least that's the case with MySQL's default init scripts.)

Comment: @wireman: that explains why other packages including knot (DNS server) have similar issues. When they decided to enforce it? I think /etc/init.d is superior as it allows shell completion thus relieves user from excessive typing. Progress to the power of -1 :)

Comment: @too Bash tab completion is customizable. Don't have anything Ubuntu handy, but seems odd that nobody would have thought of tab-completing `service` names. Maybe submit a feature request to Canonical through their bug tracker?

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log # if you see here something like "another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files", then there is another and you have to kill it e.g. via pkill mysql or service mysql restart

Comment: @too The `service` autocompletion is available in Ubuntu 18.04, I am not sure at which version it was added, but it is available nowadays. I've always thought the `init.d` scripts are ugly, so I'm glad `service` is being used more and more

Answer (score 22):

The most common cause of this problem is trying to start MySQL when it is already running.

To resolve it, kill off any running instances of MySQL and then restart it using your normal startup scripts, e.g. `service mysql start`.

Don't attempt to start MySQL manually when using distribution-packaged versions unless you are prepared for a world of hurt.

Comment: `however the mySQL server keeps crashing` - I don't restart mySQL. It just crashes itself, after which I do need to restart it obviously. ;-)

Comment: @MichaelHampton can you give little more info about 'world of hurt' and 'start MySQL manually'? Thanks)

Answer (score 6):

**This helped me to solve it:**

Delete all ibdata files and let mysql create them.

stop mysql:

```
service mysql stop
```

go to mysql library:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/
```

move innodb files somewhere in case you need it:

```
mv ib* /root/
```

start mysql:

```
service mysql start
```

Comment: Scrolling through helpful answers I thought surely this looks like it will work since the error is complaining about not being able to lock that file. After moving, mysql did recreate them but still is complaining... crazy!

Answer (score 3):

Check space to make sure it is 100%

```
df -h
```

As if its full it wont create .sock file.

Comment: The answer is about a surprising side-effect, I strongly disagree it would be LQ.

Answer (score 2):

As other users are reporting, this is usually due to MySQL not being properly terminated upon `systemctl stop mysql.service` .

I noticed on **Ubuntu 18.04** that filling in the root password twice in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` made systemctl stop and start the MySQL server process properly which eliminated the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Came here from googling of the same repeating error but with error code 13 (`InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 13`). After trying lot of solutions around the internet, invented one that helped me (apparmor!)

Add these lines to the config `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` (and reload apparmor and mysql of course):

```
/path/to/mysql/data/ r,
/path/to/mysql/data/** rwk,
```

The main differences between often solutions: two rules (for dir itself and for all files inside, note the double `**`) and `k` option to allow mysql to lock files.

Hope this help someone.

Comment: You can also add it to `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld`. Create the file if it doesn't exist. For more details, please see `/etc/apparmor.d/local/README`

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have `pid-file` parameter in the `[mysql]` section of  `my.cnf` file.
If it is not present, the `unable to lock ...ibdata1.. error:1` will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but faster than the way with "cp -a". And helped when "cp -a" and everything other couldn't.

1. `service mysql stop && pkill -f mysql`

Get rid of all mysql processes

2. `vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Change parameter datadir=/var/lib/mysql to datadir=/var/lib/mysql2 (or just add if you don't have)

3. `mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql2`

Rename datadir to a new name

4. `service mysql start`

Prepare your tambourine

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other solutions work, the problem probably stems from AppArmor misconfiguration.

So just do:

```
$ apt install apparmor-profiles
```

and then restart MySQL (notice how fast it'll restart).

I noticed a file missing related to AppArmor when doing:

```
$ systemctl status mysql.service
```

Hence why I thought something was wrong with AppArmor's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing a similar issue `Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11` while running `MySQL` in a container with `EFS` shared volume on `AWS ECS` (to persist `MySQL` between Instances lifecycle)

The issue was another Instance was accessing the volume filesystem, causing `MySQL` to not be able to lock the file

Solved by exiting the shared filesystem on that Instance, letting `MySQL` container lock it