# MariaDB: mysql_install_db problems

Tags: mariadb

I just install MariaDB on a clean Debian 7 machine. When I want to run `mysql_install_db`, I get this set of errors:

```
150329 18:01:27 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
150329 18:01:27 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150329 18:01:27 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150329 18:01:27 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
150329 18:01:27 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
150329 18:01:27 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150329 18:01:27 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
150329 18:01:27 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
150329 18:01:27 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150329 18:01:27 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
150329 18:01:27 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
150329 18:01:27 [Note] InnoDB: Retrying to lock the first data file
150329 18:01:28 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Error number 11 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
150329 18:03:07 [ERROR] InnoDB: Can't open './ibdata1'
150329 18:03:07 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
150329 18:03:07 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150329 18:03:07 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150329 18:03:07 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 11. Will retry for 30 seconds
150329 18:03:38 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Could not get an exclusive lock; file is probably in use by another process' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
150329 18:03:38 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
150329 18:03:38 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150329 18:03:38 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150329 18:03:38 [ERROR] Aborting

150329 18:03:38 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I looked into error 11, which means "EAGAIN" according to the MySQL 5.6 docs. I'm not sure why this isn't explained about MariaDB, as I have no clue what to do next. Who helps me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MariaDB is already running](https://serverfault.com/q/477448/126632) (because Debian started it and ran `mysql_install_db` for you).

Comment: So I can go straight to `mysql_secure_installation` now?

Comment: Yes, just move on.

Answer (score 2):

Two kinds of problems come to my mind:

1. There is another instance of mysqld running.

   Check with `ps -ef | grep mysqld`
2. You have permissions problem. Your user has no permission to write to database files. Check permissions of `./ibdata1` file.